# DSpace metadata template for separate community

Tags: templates, metadata, dspace

I am new to DSpace. I want to create a new community 'Ongoing projects' and all the submissions related to that community should have different metadata compared to normal submission. How to achieve this? Any guide will be great.

Your support on this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata input forms for the submission process are defined in `input-forms.xml`.

You define the input forms for your “Ongoing projects” in the `<form-definitions>` section, and then map them to collections (not communities) in the `<form-map>` section of the document like this:

```
<form-map>
    <name-map collection-handle=“handle-prefix/suffix" form-name=“ongoing-projects" />
    <name-map collection-handle="default" form-name="traditional" />
</form-map>
```

Please have a look at the [Submission User Interface](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC7x/Submission+User+Interface#SubmissionUserInterface-TheStructureofinput-forms.xml) section of the documentation.

Comment: Dear MartinW, Thanks a lot for your reply. I will check this. It seems like this should be done server level. Isn't it possible to do it as the admin of the DSpace repository?

Comment: You are right. `input-forms.xml` is a configuration file on your server. It is not possible to define submission forms via the web-interface for current versions of DSpace. You can define new metadata fields via the admin interface (also it is best practice to do this via config files too) to the system. But for them to be available in an input-form, you must edit `input-forms.xml`.

Comment: When I change the collection-handle to default for the new form, the default submission form changes to the ongoing-projects form. How can I change between these two forms as per the submission type?